# JQuery preventDefault not working with delegated event

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have a feed that uses AJAX to load in posts once the document is ready. Because the elements aren't ready at code execution, I have to use delegate to bind a lot of functions.

```
$(posts).delegate('.edit_comment_text','keyup',function(e){
    return false;
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == false) {

        //Post the new comment and replace the textbox with a paragraph.
        var message_area = $(this).parent('.comment_message');
        var new_message = $(this).val();
        var comment_id = $(this).closest('.group_comment').attr('data-comment');
        var url = 'functions/edit_comment.php';
        var array = {
            'comment':comment_id,
            'message':new_message
        }
        $.post(url, array, function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $(message_area).html("");
            $(message_area).text(new_message);
        });

    }



})
```

This is the code I execute on the event. I've been trying to get the browser to stop dropping down a line when the user hits enter, but this action is performed before my code is even triggered. To prove it, I put the 'return false' at the very top of the block. With that example, none of my code is run when the user hits enter, but the textarea still drops a line.

Is it something to do with JQuery's delegate that causes my function to be called after the default events? They give examples of preventing default events in their documentation, so maybe it's a version bug or something?

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `.delegate` has been replaced by [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Comment: delegated event are fired at delegate level. You need to filter it using event.target

Comment: What if you fire your event handler on `keydown` instead of `keyup`?

Comment: @Blazemonger Holy crap, I can't believe I didn't think of that, thanks! Also, I had no idea it had been replaced, I'll take a look at 'on' instead.

Comment: @roasted Thanks, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: keydown is definitely where the prevention would have to take place, if it is even possible.

Comment: @user1537360 sorry i misread your problem here

Comment: sorry, i mean this, keydown works here: http://jsfiddle.net/S3HgS/1/